# How to delete "-" file from svn?

Tags: svn, shell

Accidentally I have created file "-" (just a minus) in a directory and commited it. 
I have to delete it because its causing error on other machines:
svn: Can't convert string from 'UTF-8' to native encoding:
svn: ?\226?\128?\147

I can remove it from local directory using "rm -i *" or with python "os.remove('\xe2\x80\x93')" but those methods do not work with "svn rm".

How to delete such file from svn repository?

Comment: Have you tried 'svn rm -- -' or 'LC_ALL=C svn rm -- -'?

Comment: So it wasn't minus although it was looking almost exactly the same. I copy pasted it from "ls" and deleted it with "svn rm -- –". Thank you for quick answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try `svn rm ./-`

It might not actually be a minus, tho', but a similar-looking character.

Comment: I remember having to come up with this answer in my linux class in college.

Answer (score 8):

Usually, you need to terminate the list of command line options using a `--` marker.

Try something like `svn rm -- -`.

Same if you want to remove the directory from the file system: `rm -r -- -`.

Answer (score 2):

try `svn rm -- -`

`--` means "stop reading options".

Answer (score 1):

In some cases (at the console, for example) you might not be able to copy/paste an odd character. In that situation, you can use file globbing. It's a good idea to do `ls` before the `rm` to make sure you're not including something in the deletion that you want to keep.

Any single-character filename:

```
ls -l ?
rm ?
```

or, any single-character filename that's not an alphanumeric character or a hyphen:

```
ls -l [^a-zA-Z0-9-]
rm [^a-zA-Z0-9-]
```

Another version (locale-aware) of that would be:

```
ls -l [^[:alnum:]-]
rm [^[:alnum:]-]
```

You can combine other lists of characters and classes in addition to more globbing and specific characters.

Delete any file with a three-character name that doesn't start with "m", "s" or "y", has any second character, and ends with "1" or "9":

```
rm [^msy]?[19]
```