# Explaining the rm ./-rf "trick"

Tags: bash, unix, command-line, rm

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2306003/300807) states:

> It is amazing how many users don't know about the `rm ./-rf` or `rm -- -rf` tricks.

I am afraid to try these, but curious as to what they do. They are also very difficult to search...

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: "They are also very difficult to search..." - yes, google tends to ignore all punctuation. But there's a search engine specifically for punctuation at http://www.symbolhound.com which was created by another SO user. Searching for `rm --` results yields [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928934/how-to-delete-file-from-svn) as the fourth result whose answers explain both cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`rm ./-rf` and/or `rm -- -rf` would attempt to remove a file named, specifically, `-rf`

The only *trick* here is that you normally can't delete a file that starts with a "-" because the command will assume it's a command argument.  By preceding the file with a full path, or using the `--` option (which means, end all options) the command will no longer assume it's an argument.

It should be noted that the `--` version of this *trick* may or may not work with all shell commands either, so it's best to use the first version.

Comment: The shell makes no assumptions about the command arguments; it simply passes them through. It is the `rm` command itself that interprets `-rf` as control options and not as a file name.

Comment: You're right @JonathanLeffler, I've updated the answer to clarify.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a file named `-rf` in your directory, it is difficult to remove that file if you don't know the trick.  That's because:

```
rm -rf
```

supplies two command line options (`-r` and `-f`) as a single argument, and tells `rm` to recursively and forcibly remove things.

If you write:

```
rm ./-rf
```

the argument does not start with a dash any more, so it is simply a file name.  Similarly, by common (but not universal) convention, `--` marks the end of the option arguments and anything afterwards is no longer an option (which usually means it is a file name).  So:

```
rm -- -rf
```

removes the file because `rm` knows that the arguments that follow the `--` are file names, not options for it to process.

The file `-rf` is even more dangerous if you use wildcards:

```
rm *rf*
```

Suddenly, this will remove directories as well as files (but won't harm the file `-rf`).

Comment: Wow, `rm *rf*` does *not* do what I expected. Wildcards as options! That's scary!

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, as I think the other answers give good explanations.

When I'm unsure what a given `rm` invocation is going to delete, I try to remember to simply `ls` the file list first to make sure it is actually what I want to delete:

```
$ ls -rf
-rf  ..  .
$
```

OK, clearly thats not right, lets try again:

```
$ ls ./-rf
./-rf
$
```

Thats better.  Lets do a history replacement of `ls` with `rm -v` (`-v` just for extra paranoia/checking) and do the actual delete:

```
$ rm -v !!:*
rm -v ./-rf
removed `./-rf'
$
```

This also works nicely with wildcards, brace expansions, etc, when you're not sure what the expansion will be exactly.

---

Also if you're wondering how files like `-rf` get created in the first place, its astonishingly easy if you mess up a redirection a bit:

```
$ ls
$ echo > -rf
$ ls
-rf
$
```